# Trimming only on paste

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could I achieve trimming only on ng-paste == true. I mean, when inputs has more than maxlength="x"(using ordinary type) nothing happens, but when user paste something into input(that have more than maxlength x) the trim will be fired and input will be trimmed to x maxlength.

Comment: in Chrome, it does this by default. https://jsfiddle.net/ctjaxds5/

Comment: @EnigmaRM It's like that in all browsers, and that might be what he wants. From the way I read it, he only wants maxlength to be enforced when the user pastes and wants to go past the maxlength when the user types.

Comment: @rgvassar you're correct

Answer (score 0):

In html:

```
<input ng-paste="trim(20)" ng-model="val"  ng-init="paste=false" placeholder='paste here'>
```

In JavaScript:

```
$scope.trim = function(maxLength) {
    $scope.val = $scope.val.substring(0, maxLength);
};
```

Comment: This isn't work as native ng-trim when meet maxlength. Unfortunately it is unusable. It trims only text when was typed before the paste.